# how to fill the command buffer of the worker thread (iOS threading)

Tags: ios, multithreading

I was going over the RunLoop iOS [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW3) and it discusses the idea illustrated here:
 [image: this]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Art/custominputsource.jpg))</sub>

in the RunLoopSource it provides the following interface for client threads (ie the Main thread in the above illustration) to fill the audio buffer with commands and data, and to subsequently fire all commands available in the said buffer:

```
// Client interface for registering commands to process
- (void)addCommand:(NSInteger)command withData:(id)data
- (void)fireAllCommandsOnRunLoop:(CFRunLoopRef)runloop
```

In the add command method we're simply adding commands to an NSMutableArray data structure.

My question is how can we encapsulate those commands in variables such that they are methods.. the *data* variable in the *addCommand* method is of type *id*.. can we put a block in there for example? Are there any best practices here/sample code etc? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique pre-dates blocks. The beauty about using blocks with concurrency is that you can throw as much work as you want at the system, and given its total device scope can schedule that work on multiple cores and threads as it sees fit. You can also use a concurrent NSOperation and have it implement a fifo to accept work and process it, but in this case there will only be the secondary thread, and it will again be scheduled run time as the system sees fit to giving it, so no advantage over blocks.

Comment: my problem with blocks and NSOperations is that i'm not clear about how I can have threads communicate back and forth and how one the main thread can tell the worker thread that something has changed (how can i even identify the worker thread)? If you can refer me to some documentation that may address some of these concerns I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can message them as you would any other object. The problem occurs when you try to add an object to an array (for example) since mutable objects are not thread safe. A NSOperation has a single thread that it can ask NSThread for, and make available as a property. The main class can message that operation by using the 'performSelector' variant that takes a thread parameter. The operation can message the main object by messaging the mainThread (there is a performSelector variant for that too). To experiment with a Concurrent Operations see: xhttps://github.com/dhoerl/Concurrent_NSOperations

Comment: let's say i'm working with an app that has several threads running at the same time.. some are already done using the old manual techniques, + it manually locks etc.. is it possible to run some threads using modern techniques like NSOperations and still have it communicate with those other threads?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same technique - message them on their thread, have them message you on the mainThread.

Comment: I was doing some readings about NSoperation and operations queues etc.. and the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW14) says the following: Threads are still a good way to implement code that must run in real time. Dispatch queues make every attempt to run their tasks as fast as possible but they do not address real time constraints. That concerns me as my application is real time..

Comment: Well, if you read Apple's Concurrency document they begin it with a statement that there are virtually no reasons to use threads now. Just because you have a thread doesn't mean its getting more access to the CPU than a block or operation. I have a wine label scanner app (private) that takes 20 photos per second and stitches them together. I did it using blocks, and when I tested it on a 4S phone, it virtually ran at twice the speed due to the second core, no code changes required. YMMV.

Comment: thanks for your patience @David H
I've spent most of today on your github code.. and it seems to run real nice.. but I have this quesiton.. in the code you got this: NSMutableData *webData; // when the operation is over, fetch the data - no contention.. the problem is that in my code I want to have a shared data (which is basically an NSMutableArray.. not thread safe i guess) that I want both master and worker threads to read from/write to.. How can I do that using your code's architecture? Thing is I'm new to multi-threading so this may be a dumb quesiton